# Using geoNear in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I've been trying to determine the distance of ninjas from a geoLocation point with mongoose. I've tried everything, but somehow I cannot find the correct documentation for Mongoose, these are some new changes.

Like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Ninja = require('../models/ninja');

// get a list of ninjas from the database
router.get('/ninjas', (req, res, next) => {
    Ninja.aggregate([
        {
            $geoNear: {
                near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ parseFloat(req.query.lng) , parseFloat(req.query.lat) ] },
                maxDistance: 100000,
                distanceField: "distance",
                spherical: true
            }
        }
    ]).then(function(ninjas){
        res.send(ninjas);
    }).catch(next)
});
```

Still, when I add the params to the URL via Postman, I cannot find it.

This is my Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// CREATE GEOLOCATION SCHEMA
const GeoSchema = new Schema({
   type:{
       type: String,
       default: "Point"
   },
   coordinates: {
       type: [Number],
       index: "2dsphere"
   }
});

// CREATE NINJA SCHEMA AND MODEL
const NinjaSchema = new Schema({
    "name": {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Name field is required']
    },
    "rank": {
        type: String,
    },
    "available": {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    "geometry": GeoSchema
});

const Ninja = mongoose.model('ninja', NinjaSchema);

module.exports = Ninja;
```

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer? If not, may I know the error you get in your server logs?

Comment: Are you sure the query parameters are in the right order? For example, your get request should be like /ninjas?lng=-80&lat=25 depending on whether you have a ninja whose location is longitude -80.*** and latitude 25.***

Answer (score 0):

correct your ninja model and schema code

```
// create ninja Schema & model
const NinjaSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Name field is required']
},
rank: {
    type: String
},
available: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
},
geometry: GeoSchema
```

});